# NestJs Typeorm drops foreign key column, even if set to not null

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have recently added a foreign key (authorId) relation to the questions table, each question should have userId associated with it.

Every time I start the server it drops the foreign key (authorId) column, in local development

`synchronize: true` https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2137

[image]

I thought it was a version compatibility issue, I have tried changing the npm module mysql and mysql2, and downgraded MySQL 8 to MySQL 5.7. Nothing works.

Even used `postgresql` doesn't work

Is there a solution for this? OR Should I use `sequelize` or something else?

Question.entity.ts File

[image: Qestion Entity File]

User.entity.ts File

[image: User Entity File]

**Update:** This issue is happening only when i run with `npm run start:dev`, it is fine when run with `npm start`.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you remember how you solved it back then by any chance?

Comment: It was file system issue for me, I was using windows and WSL. Deleted the code cloned again and npm install

Comment: Could you attach the code as text, not as an image?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add { eager: true } at your entity like :

```
@OneToOne(() => ToToEntity,{ nullable: true, eager: true } )
@JoinColumn()
toto: ToToEntity;
```

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4522

Answer (score 0):

Try to change synchronize mode to `synchronize: false` in `ormconfig.json`. Every time the server restart, the foreign keys are restarted as well. You can learn how to use migrations and seeds instead, especially when it comes to production

> Once you get into production you'll need to synchronize model changes into the database. Typically it is unsafe to use synchronize: true for schema synchronization on production once you get data in your database.

Typeorm - Migrations : https://typeorm.io/#/migrations

Answer (score 0):

17 Aug 2022,

If there's anyone experiencing this issue with `synchronize: true` set, try running `yarn prebuild`. That fixed the issue for me.

I found the resolved issue here.
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6871